# Can't connect to open secure port on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I opened the 8443 port on which I run Clickhouse server. I can connect to SSH on 22 port, I can also connect to 8443 via SSH tunnel, however I can't connect normally to that host. I'm trying to connect from the Windows machine, if that is related anyhow. I even opened outbound port (pretty sure that it is redundant).

I tried to disable firewall and then I was able to connect. What can be wrong?

```bsh
user@myhost:~/d/clickhouse$ sudo ufw status
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
9440/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8443/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8443                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
9440/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8443 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

user@myhost:~/d/clickhouse$ sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P
COMMAND      PID            USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-r    841 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4   26021      0t0  TCP localhost:53 (LISTEN)
vsftpd       901            root    3u  IPv6   26299      0t0  TCP *:21 (LISTEN)
sshd        1037            root    3u  IPv4   29181      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd        1037            root    4u  IPv6   29183      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
docker-pr  86081            root    4u  IPv6  520074      0t0  TCP *:8088 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 287023            root    4u  IPv6 1831110      0t0  TCP *:8086 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 318522            root    4u  IPv6 2109586      0t0  TCP *:9440 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 318537            root    4u  IPv6 2110806      0t0  TCP *:8443 (LISTEN)
node      354955           user   18u  IPv4 2274703      0t0  TCP localhost:34575 (LISTEN)

user@myhost:~/d/clickhouse$ netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34575         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8086                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::9440                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

UPDATE:

on the server I ran `sudo tcpdump -ni eth0 port 8443` and then on client machine I ran `nc -zv 192.168.1.58 8443`:

```bsh
user@myhost:~$ sudo tcpdump -ni eth0 port 8443
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:05:51.368952 IP 192.168.1.70.59364 > 192.168.1.58.8443: Flags [S], seq 2263747478, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1434934937 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:05:52.380268 IP 192.168.1.70.59364 > 192.168.1.58.8443: Flags [S], seq 2263747478, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1434935948 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:05:54.460280 IP 192.168.1.70.59364 > 192.168.1.58.8443: Flags [S], seq 2263747478, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1434938028 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:05:58.540705 IP 192.168.1.70.59364 > 192.168.1.58.8443: Flags [S], seq 2263747478, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1434942109 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:06:06.940802 IP 192.168.1.70.59364 > 192.168.1.58.8443: Flags [S], seq 2263747478, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1434950509 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:06:23.581056 IP 192.168.1.70.59364 > 192.168.1.58.8443: Flags [S], seq 2263747478, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1434967149 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:06:56.221198 IP 192.168.1.70.59364 > 192.168.1.58.8443: Flags [S], seq 2263747478, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1434999788 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

and `nc` failed with the message `nc: connect to 192.168.1.58 port 8443 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out`

The output of `sudo ufw status verbose`

```bsh
user@myhost:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
9440/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
8443/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
8443                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
9440/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
8443 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
8443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I can connect to service if firewall is disabled:

```bsh
nc -zv 192.168.1.58 8443 
Connection to 192.168.1.58 8443 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

I can connect to service with IPv4 address if firewall is disabled:
[image]

Comment: At first glance it appears you have opened 8443 (ufw) on IPv4 but it is listening only on IPv6 (lsof/netstat output). Try `sudo ufw disable` and see if it works then.

Comment: just to be clear, `ufw disable` is just for a quick test. If it then works do `sudo ufw enable` and open 8443 on IPv6 as well (something like `sudo ufw allow from any to any port 8443`

Comment: @WayneVosberg it worked with disabled firewall. After that I ran your command and still can't connect. I updated the question with the new results for netstat/lsof

Comment: I also tried to run `sudo ufw allow proto tcp from any to any port 8443`. Updated `ufw status` part as well

Comment: Your `netstat` output shows that some service is listening on port 8443 **only on IPv6 address**. Nothing at all is listening on port 8443 on IPv4 address. This has nothing to do with firewall, but with the service configuration itself. For some reason the service binds only to IPv6 address. You must check the configuration.

Comment: @raj then how can I connect to it by specifying IPv4 address when firewall is disabled? (added screenshot)

Comment: I can only guess - is there something configured on your server that redirects connections from IPv4 to IPv6 ? I see your service is running in the Docker container, then that "something" can sit somewhere on the Docker level, between your host OS and the service itself. And maybe firewall interferes with that "something". I think it will be better if the service listened directly on IPv4.

Comment: that's weird as I see from the `docker ps` that the port is forwarded to the IPv4 port, as well from all the configurations I can see the same: `2229b0ce11e7   test/clickhouse   "/entrypoint.sh"         2 days ago   Up 2 days             8123/tcp, 9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp, 9009/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9440->9440/tcp   clickhouse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I fixed that by running following command: `sudo ufw route allow proto tcp from any to any port 8443`